# MS Excel Function: Get data from a cell of a particular column and the current row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I just want to say up front that I have very little skill in Excel.
Actually, I never use it.

What I have been trying to do is create a function that gets the *value of a cell* of a *particular column* and the *current row*.

---

For example, I want the value of cell:

**Column:** B

**Row:** ROW()

---

What I will ultimately use this to do is average cells in a row.
If there's a better way to do that, feel free to give suggestions, although it would still be neat to learn how to do this if it's possible. =)

I apologize if I messed up in presenting or posting my question; aside from Excel, I'm also new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Normally you can just refer to the cell directly, e.g. in row 2 use `=B2` - when you copy that formula down the column it will change to B3, B4, B5 etc. as you copy down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of cell (B,ROW()) do:

```
= INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B", ROW()))
```

If you just want to calculate the average of a given line of numbers (e.g. first 10 cells in row 2):

```
= AVERAGE(A2:J2)
```

The ':' represents an area from the upper left corner (A2) to the lower right (J2).

As mentioned by @MattClarke, you can use `=AVERAGE(ROW_NUMBER:ROW_NUMBER)` to calculate the average of a whole row (in this case row ROW_NUMBER) where you don't know the exact number of data fields. Pay attention not to use this formula in that exact row (row ROW_NUMBER) to avoid a circular reference. (Thanks @MattClarke for the hint!)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the average across a fixed range of cells is pretty easy: just use a formula like `=average(A4:H4)` where the parameter specifies the first and last cell. If you want the average of a whole row and you don't know how many columns of data there are, then you can use something like `=average(8:8)`, where the number 8 is the row number of the data to be averaged.

Comment: Unfortunately, @johk95 is not quite right about using `=AVERAGE(ROW():ROW())` -- Excel won't allow the use of row() in that context, so it has to be an literal integer for the row number. Even if Excel did allow that formula, it would try to calculate the average of all cells in the *current* row, which would include the cell in which you were putting the formula and hence be a circular reference.